Rsync freezes the target machine - unless it is running a small monitoring program
Due to data security, I need to perform a rsync operation on a primary server to "backup" all updated data to an off-site, backup machine. (both machines are running linux)
In the past, there is no problem because the data volume is very small, but as time goes on, the data volume becomes quite big and recently we've found that after performing the rsync (from source to the target), the target machine will freeze and hang (always)
But interestingly, if we open a remote console and run a small, monitoring program (e.g. top) on the target machine and THEN perform the rsync, the rsync operation will NOT cause the target to hang !
Does anyone know what is happening ?  Please kindly advise. Thanks

Does the entire machine hang, or only the SSH connection to it?  Does it freeze forever or does it un-freeze by itself? Does it freeze during transfer (i.e. network activity) or does it freeze during the initial scan (i.e. no network activity while rsync is comparing data)?

It (whole machine) freezes forever unless reboot - network also unresponsive - it freezes after rsync has run for around 5 minutes. After reboot checking the log it says memory error / exhausted (something like that) -- but if I run top on the target machine first (before performing rsync) , the rsync will proceed until it is completed and the target machine will not hang (interesting , Ah Ha?)
